# Unable to verify SSL certificate issuer for LDAP server

Tags: linux, debian, ssl-certificate, openldap, openssl

I have just setup SSL on my LDAP server by following this guide - http://www.linux.com/archive/feature/114087

I have made a self signed certificate using openSSL and set it up. When something tries to connect to the server using SSL it comes up with an error saying "The issuer of the certificate could not be found"

The common name is set to ldap.redmeetsblue.com.au which is pointing to our network, only port 636 is forwarded to the machine .

Ive looked over the internet but cannot find an answer, im pretty new to this so im stumped

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

you have to add the self-signed certificate as trusted to your client certificate store.
This way the client will accept it and establish a connection.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using a certificate signed by your own certificate authority (CA), rather than a globally recognized one (such as verisign, etc), you need to configure LDAP clients to recognize your CA, by telling them to trust the CA's certificate.

For the ldap* command line clients, this can be done by adding the following line to /etc/ldap/ldap.conf or /etc/ldap.conf:

> TLSCACertificateFile /etc/ldap/cacert.pem

(I'm guessing this is where your CA certificate is, based on the link you posted. You will of course need to distribute this file to other clients.)

Hope this helps.

Comment: The actual option for the client is TLS_CACERT. TLSCACertificateFile is the same but for the server (which may use it to check client certificates).